# An i.i.d. sum of function of normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $V_1,V_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. How does one find the distribution of
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(\frac{2}{1+e^{-2V_i}}\right).$$

I  can derive the distribution for $S_1$ and the expression is a little cumbersome.
I understand that the next step is to convolve this distribution with itself. 
I am stuck there, I am not able to reduce the expression at all!

Comment: Just a hint: Try to use the central limit theorem. If it can be applied then even for relatively small $n$s the distribution can be approximated by the Gaussian. You have to normalize. But you know the distribution of $S_1$.